# Can we still call this one as a builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Here is my factory-method class.

```
public class AFactory : FactoryBase {
        public override ProductBase ProduceProdut() {
            return new SuperCoolProduct();
        }
}
```

Here is my builder class.

```
public class ABuilder : BuilderBase {

        ProductBase product = new SuperCoolProduct()

        public override void BuildStep1() {
             //Do Something (e.g. product.Add() )
        }
        public override void BuildStep2() {
             //Do some more...(e.g. product.AddMore() ) 
        }

        public override ProductBase GetFinalProduct() {
            return product;
        }
}
```

My questions are the following ~

1) Does the builder has to expose some methods that the Director can call for compositing the product?

Can this class still be considered as a builder class? Or, Do we have to call it as a factory class? I think that we can't call this class below as a builder anymore and it's a factory class now..

```
public class ABuilder : BuilderBase {

            ProductBase product = new SuperCoolProduct();        

            public override ProductBase GetFinalProduct() {
                BuildStep1();    
                BuildStep2();

                return product;
            }

            private void BuildStep1() {
                 //Do Something (e.g. product.Add() )
            }
            private void BuildStep2() {
                 //Do some more...(e.g. product.AddMore() ) 
            }

    }
```

2)  Would the code below be a good example of combining "Builder" pattern and "Factory Method" pattern?

```
public class AFactory : FactoryBase {

                BuilderBase builder;

                public AFactory(BuilderBase builder){
                   this.builder = builder;
                }
                public override ProductBase ProduceProdut() {
                    this.builder.BuildStep1();
                    this.builder.BuildStep1();
                    return this.builder.GetFinalProduct();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. I would call it a director. But yes. You could call it a factory method implementation.

As for factories: It's more common to call the methods `CreateXXX`